# Returning value from recursion

Tags: python, recursion, stack

I was following a tutorial to `All unique combinations whose sum equals to K` from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-unique-combinations-whose-sum-equals-to-k/). I need to tinker with the program to return the first unique combination found.

So I modified the code to return a `final` array which I pass in the `combination_rec` as well. Debugging the code in I see that the state of `final` is not maintained across the recursive stack, I get `[]` as the returned value.

```py
import copy

def combination(arr, sum):
    arr.sort(reverse=False)
    local = []
    res = combination_rec(0, 0, sum, local, arr, [])
    if res:
        return res
    return []

def combination_rec(length, total, sum, local, arr, final):
    if total == sum:
        final = copy.copy(local)
        return final

    for i in range(length, len(arr), 1):

        if total + arr[i] > sum:
            continue

        if (i > length and arr[i] == arr[i - 1]):
            continue

        local.append(arr[i])

        final = combination_rec(i + 1, total + arr[i], sum, local, arr, final)

        local.remove(local[len(local) - 1])
        
        return final


if __name__ == "__main__":
    combination([6, 5, 4, 3], 8)
```

```
Expected Output
--------
[3,5]
```

```
Actual Output
--------
[]
```

Summary of the program

1. Sorts the array - `[3, 4, 4, 5, 6]`
2. Loops over its elements to check each possible combination of elements which can sum up to K (8)
3. Begins with 3. Checks if subarray  [3, 4] totals 8. It does not.
   So it modifies the sub-array to include [3, 4, 5]. As this total (12) > 8
4. It goes back to line `local.remove(local[len(local) - 1])` to remove 5 from sub-array and proceed to consider subsequent elements in the sorted array
5. Checks for [3,4,6].
6. Removes 6, followed by removal of 4.
7. Next check is for [3, 5]. This matches the total and this is when I wish to return `final` as [3, 5]

What is it I am doing wrong?

**PS:** I know that step 4 - the subsequent for loop iterations - is redundant. It does not make sense to check for [3,4,6] when [3,4,5] yielded a sum greater than it. But that's not my concern right. I am trying to understand returning values from recursion

Comment: You have an indentation problem. The return statement is inside the for loop (`return final`)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ThomasWeller, I got the point. Shouldn't it work without the `return final` as well?

Comment: No, that won't work, because you need a value to assign in the line `res = combination_rec(...)`. Otherwise `rec` would have the value `None`

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was asking if I remove the `return final` from the main function, and only keep it in the if clause (the base case)